# Parler français comme une vache espagnole

Tags: expressions, origine-ou-raison

Cette expression un tant soit peu colorée signifie ne pas bien parler la langue française. Or, jusqu'à tout récemment, je n'avais entendu cette expression qu'avec la langue anglaise : Parler anglais comme une vache espagnole.

Existe-t-il d'autres variantes de cette expression, et quelle est son origine?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Par extension, je pense qu'on peut l'appliquer à n'importe quelle langue. Le [Wiktionnaire](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/fr/wiki/parler_fran%C3%A7ais_comme_une_vache_espagnole) donne cette origine pour l’expression

> Certains pensent que cette locution est une déformation de parler français comme un Basque espagnol, mais celle-ci n’est pas attestée dans les ouvrages anciens. Peut-être a-t-elle simplement été formée à partir de vache, comme l’autre locution *être sorcier comme une vache espagnole*.
>
> Une autre hypothèse a été proposée par Pierre Marie Quitard  : *II fut un temps où les habitants du nord de l’Espagne, voisins des contrées méridionales de la France, en parlaient usuellement le langage, tandis que les habitants du midi de l’Espagne avaient un idiome différent, et les premiers, faisant allusion à cette différence, disaient dérisoirement de quelqu’un qui commettait des fautes grossières contre le français, qu’il le parlait comme un* baxo. *Or ce mot* baxo, *qu’on employait pour désigner un Espagnol du bas pays ou du midi de la Péninsule, et qu’on prononçait* baco, *fut bientôt changé en* vaco *(vache), et de là vint la locution proverbiale.*

[Expressio](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/parler-francais-comme-une-vache-espagnole.php) cite aussi Alain Rey

> « Comme une vache » était en général, et est toujours, un terme intensif à connotation fortement négative. Et, à la date d'apparition de l'expression, *espagnol* était également un qualificatif désagréable ; on disait en effet *payer à l'espagnole* pour quelqu'un qui *payait* en donnant des coups ou on désignait une *fanfaronnade* d'*espagnolade*.
> Alors la combinaison de ces deux termes, qu'on trouve dans la littérature dans l'expression *il est sorcier comme une vache espagnole* (c'est un incapable), aurait été un moyen de qualifier très négativement la manière de parler un mauvais français.

Answer (score 3):

L’origine de cette expression pourrait venir de « [Parler français comme un Basque l’espagnol](http://www.langue-fr.net/spip.php?article253) ».

Comment: J'ai toujours cru que cette variante était une idée de [Coluche](http://www.wat.tv/audio/coluche-tous-chemins-menent-rome-1rf7p_2h9vt_.html)...